# Difference between generics <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> and T extends Comparable<? extends Number>

Tags: java, generics

Can someone explain the difference between `<T extends Number & Comparable<T>>` and `T extends Comparable<? extends Number>`?

These look similar to me and both of them compiles fine for sub classes type. The invalid type args shows below error

> Type parameter is not within bound parameter;should implement
>   'java.lang.Number'

and

> Type parameter is not within bound parameter; should extend
>   'java.lang.Comparable>'

respectively.

Comment: Show your code. What error are you talking about? When do you get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use:

```
Comparable<? extends Number>
```

because the only methods defined by `Comparable` are *consumers* (in the sense of [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)): it needs to accept instances of type `? extends Number` into its `compareTo` method - and there is no type which satisfies that bound safely.

`Integer` is a `Comparable<? extends Number>`, but so is `Double`. Thus, you can't safely call `instance1.compareTo(instance2)` because it would fail if these instances are concretely `Integer` and `Double` respectively, since `Integer.compareTo` can only accept `Integer` parameters.

As such, the compiler prevents you from calling this method in the first place.

Comment: when you say there are no types what do you mean ? Is Integer class not a type that will satisfy the bound ?

Comment: @ShivV: He means that a value of type `T` won't be able to `.compareTo()` anything.

Comment: @ShivV Edited my answer to add more explanation.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

> Option 1:

```
public class A <T extends Number & Comparable<T>>{}
```

Your Generic Parameter should extend Number **and** implements Comparable, 
which means class A is a Number and Comparable.

> Option 2:

```
public class B <T extends Comparable<? extends Number>>{}
```

T is Comparable on Numbers(can compare Number only) but doesn't have to be a Number, unlike option 1

**I will explain by example:**

**A**

```
public class A <T extends Number & Comparable<T>>{}
```

**B**

```
public class B <T extends Comparable<? extends Number>>{}
```

**IntegerWrapper**(Option 2)

```
    public class IntegerWrapper implements Comparable<Integer>  {

      Integer number;

      public IntegerWrapper(int number) {
        this.number = number;
      }

      @Override
      public int compareTo(Integer o) {
        return number.compareTo(o);
      }
    }
```

**GenericsTest**
    public class GenericsTest {

```
  public static void main(String args[]){
    A myA = new A<Integer>();

    B myB = new B<IntegerWrapper>();
  }
}
```

I think option 1 is what you are looking for, because i can't think of many useful scenarios for Option 2(Maybe there is...)

Comment: "T is Comparable on Numbers(can compare Number only) but doesn't have to be a Number" Can you elaborate a little more ?

Comment: T is Comparable for Number types, but does not have to extend Number class like option 1 -> T extends Number, its only Comparable<T>. and was defined as T extends Number. from my example IntegerWrapper does not extend Number class, but implements  Comparable<Integer>